# Qlikview Report for one Category with Charts that Contain Other Metrics

Tags: report, qlikview

I am trying to create a report that all updates according to one location out of 35. In essence, I have 35 locations and so I will filter on one of the locations to update the whole report with data that relates to that location. However, there are charts I want to create that should be summed for the whole country, but I am having a hard time creating charts with all 35 dimensions because I don't want to unclick my filter.

For example, I want one table that has all 35 locations and their respective categories (e.g., total score, total employer score, etc), but I can only achieve this table if I do not click on any of the locations in the "locations" field.

Is there an expression I need to specify for the dimension "locations" that will show all dimensions, even if I have one of them selected for the rest of the report?

Comment: Did you try to use set analysis to create your Chart over the 35 locations?

Comment: I think the question in the title is different to the description. Maybe you should adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bookmarks in [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview) to store different filters, and you can create diagrams and tables that are independent form the current selection using `set analaysis`.

(I'm not sure if that also applies to the dimenension.)